# Highcharts - Remove first marker from Area chart in every series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts. How can I remove first marker point from every series of chart item?

I have tried with:

```
$('.highcharts-markers path').last().remove();
```

But it is getting deleted only for one series.

> **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0s2pkps0/4/)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching every single `path` element that is a descendant of a `.highcharts-marker` element, and then removing the very last of them. That is never going to remove more than 1 element.

Instead you could match a set of elements, one for each series, like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kg702t/)):

```
$('.highcharts-markers > path:last-child').remove();
```

It find all the `path` elements that are the last child of their parent element, and their parent should be the `.highcharts-markers` element. Then it removes all the matched elements.

Comment: **@Halvor Strand**, working like GEM... Thanks for the TIP